# How to autowire spring stream cloud bindings

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-messaging

I defined `error` and `notification` bindings in `application.yml`

```
cloud:
  stream:
    bindings:
      error:
        destination: error
        binder: default
      notification:
        destination: notification
        binder: default
```

How can i get those beans in my components?

I tried this approach:

```
@Component
class MyComponent {

   @Autowired
   @Qualified("notification")
   MessageChannel notificationChannel;
}
```

But `notificationChanel` is not found.

**Update**
`cloud.stream.bindings.*` allow only configure channels. But does not create it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you have `@EnableBinding` and appropriate interface to declare `@Input` or `@Output`?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_declaring_and_binding_channels

```
public interface Barista {

    @Input
    SubscribableChannel orders();

    @Output
    MessageChannel hotDrinks();

    @Output
    MessageChannel coldDrinks();
}

...
@EnableBinding(Barista.class)
public class CafeConfiguration {
```

Comment: Thanks for response. If i have defined Interface with this Channels application will work. But i want to move channels information from code to configuration.

Comment: No, that isn't possible. The interface must be there any way. At least that is how I see that...

Comment: You may rely on the on the built-in `Source`, `Sink` and `Processor` though.

Comment: Consider to investigate samples: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples

Comment: So, you don't have choice with the custom channels unless declare interface. That is how Framework works. That's all. The binding feature is definitely about binding element. And we have to let Framework to know to what object we are going to bind - `MessageChannel`, `Flux`, `KStream` etc..

Comment: Yes, you are right. Interfaces is absolutely necessary here. No another way. Thanks. This config allow to configure channels in created beans.

Comment: Good to know we are in an agreement. Time to accept the answer to let other people to know that here is a good info!

Comment: `@EnableBindings` `@Input` and `@Output` have been deprecated in Spring 3.1

Comment: That's correct, but the question was asked long time ago, so the answer was relevant to the API we had back then.